# sort array by property without using the first object

Tags: arrays, angular

I have an array of objects and I want to sort them by the object ids.
I tried using 
`options.sort((a, b) => a.id.localeCompare(b.id));`
 but did not worked as expected because it is sorting even the 'all' object and I don't want this (the object with id='all' should be first in my array, after that should be the objects in ascending order). Below you can see the input and the output of my code

Input:

```
 var items = 
           [{ 'Name':'All', 'id': 'all'
            { 'Name':'item1', 'id': '003' }
            { 'Name':'item2', 'id': '001' }
            { 'Name':'item3', 'id': '002' }];
```

Output:

```
  var items = 
           [{ 'Name':'item2', 'id': '001' }
            { 'Name':'item3', 'id': '002' }
            { 'Name':'item1', 'id': '003' }
            { 'Name':'All', 'id': 'all'}];
```

Comment: answer modified in a comment again with clean syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work

```js
var items = 
           [{ 'Name':'All', 'id': 'all' },
            { 'Name':'item1', 'id': '003' },
            { 'Name':'item2', 'id': '001' },
            { 'Name':'item3', 'id': '002' }];
            
   items.sort((a, b) => ((typeof b.id === "number") - (typeof a.id === "number")) || (a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1));

// items.sort((a, b) => (((typeof b.id === "number") as any) - ((typeof a.id === "number") as any)) || (a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1) );

  console.log(items)
```

Comment: I get this error 'The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.' for the typeof part..

Comment: Updated the answer. Try the commented one for type support

Comment: @user2004 The answer is modified again in a comment with a clean syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function compare(key, order = 'desc') {
  return (a, b) => {
    if (a[key] > b[key])
      return order === 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
    if (a[key] < b[key])
      return order === 'desc' ? 1 : -1;
    return 0;
  };
 }


const data = [
      { 'Name':'All', 'id': 'all'},
      { 'Name':'item3', 'id': '003' },
      { 'Name':'item1', 'id': '001' },
      { 'Name':'item2', 'id': '002' }
 ];
 
 const sortedData = data.sort(compare('Name', 'asce'));
 console.log('sorted: ', sortedData);
```